# Cucumber - global transform or expression

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I would like to be able to map string from step to DTO in java.

I found that I can do this with `@Transform(DtoTransformer.class)` annotation before each step definition where i need this (e.g. `public void theDtoOfSomethingIs(@Transform(DtoTransformer.class) Dto currentDto) {...`). The problem here is that I need to repeat `@Transform` and don't know how to register it globally.

Other option I have is to use `cucumber-expressions`, and do registration of converter using this:

```
ParameterType<Dto> dto= new ParameterType<>(
                "dto",
                "(\\d+)",
                Dto.class,
                new SingleTransformer<>(s -> Dto.of(Integer.parseInt(s)))
        );
ParameterTypeRegistry parameterTypeRegistry = new ParameterTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);
parameterTypeRegistry.defineParameterType(dto);
```

and in theory I should be able to use step definitions like this `@Given("^the dto of something is {dto}$");`.

Problem here is that this does not work since I don't know how to register `ParameterTypeRegistry` to be automatically picked up by cucumber.

Hope somebody has experience with using this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the feature of registering custom XStreamConverters for this purpose. Please take a look at examples in the following pull request of cucumber-jvm: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1010.